# pass arguments to thread after starting it

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a way one can pass arguments to a thread after starting it, or is there a way to change the `state` variable inside the thread so that the while loop stops executing and i can kill the thread safely

`file.py`

```
def test(state):
    while state:
        print (f" Current Bot state : {state} ")
```

`main.py`

```
from time import sleep
from file import test
from threading import Thread

test_thread = Thread(target=test, args=(True,))
test_thread.start()

sleep(3)

test_thread.join()
```

Comment: Look into `threading.Event`

Comment: @timgeb can you elaborate where should i use it and or how to use it

Comment: You can pass in a dictionary, then change the values in it across the threads (or some other mutable type; list, set, object...)

Comment: @prometheus, an `Event` object is dirt simple. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects).